# What do the voice commands in Dead Rising 3 do?

Tags: dead-rising-3

I've seen in the top right corner of my screen the symbol of the microphone and a few words.   Example: When I was in a boss fight, the text said, "You're Crazy!"   I would yell those words (as my kinect is connected to my Xbox One) and it seemed like nothing would happen in the game.  The microphone symbol though would change from white to blue.

What do these voice commands do?

Are there other voice commands I can yell in game?

(Besides "save game", "normal play" [at menu])

Answer (score 1):

"You're crazy" will distract certain bosses, meaning you can use a beat down(?) on them.

"Over here" will attract Zombies to your location.
"Scavenge" will make your posse look for items.
"Follow" makes you posse follow you.
"Attack" makes your posse attack nearby zombies.
"Go"makes your posse run infront of you.